# Why need "-1" in my For loops php

Tags: php

Good day, Please check my script first.

```
    for($x = 0;$x<=count($outlet);$x++)
        {
        echo $x."  insert into arealeader 
                (
            [Kodearealeader],[OutletCode],[NipLeader],[NipChief],[NipRM],[CutOff],[flag],[CreatedBy],[CreatedDate]) 
              values ('$generatecode[$x]','$outlet[$x]','$leader[$x]','$chief[$x]','$regionalmanager[$x]','$periode','1','$nip_login','$DateNow->time'
             )<br>";
        }
```

My problem is when i only insert two outlets from my form. the result will show 3 lines. But it will working fine when i do this `for($x = 0;$x<=count($outlet)-1;$x++)`

result

```
0 insert into arealeader ( [Kodearealeader],[OutletCode],[NipLeader],[NipChief],[NipRM],[CutOff],[flag],[CreatedBy],[CreatedDate]) values ( 'K','CF-LBS','','4141413','9191','','1','1602762','2016-04-29 10:09:56.640' )
1 insert into arealeader ( [Kodearealeader],[OutletCode],[NipLeader],[NipChief],[NipRM],[CutOff],[flag],[CreatedBy],[CreatedDate]) values ( 'L','K-ATR2','','4141413','9191','','1','1602762','2016-04-29 10:09:56.640' )
2 insert into arealeader ( [Kodearealeader],[OutletCode],[NipLeader],[NipChief],[NipRM],[CutOff],[flag],[CreatedBy],[CreatedDate]) values ( '0','','','','','','1','1602762','2016-04-29 10:09:56.640' )
```

`echo count($outlet)` result is `2`

Comment: php arrays are `0` indexed. So a basic array of `$array = [1,2,3]` has `count($array)` of `3`, but the indexes are `0,1,2` not `1,2,3`. So in your loop  you use `-1` to get the count of the `0` index, ie. `2` instead of `3`.

Comment: @Sean Well, or better yet... `$x < count($outlet)`...

Comment: or just use foreach() and let php do the index stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing `x` to 0. Then executing `echo` once with `x` in this state. `x` then increments to 1. 1 is still less than or equal to 2, so the `echo` runs again. `x` increments again to 2, which is still less than or equal to 2, so the `echo` executes a third time. What you probably want to do is replace `$x<=count($outlet)` with `$x<count($outlet)`, as you really want 'less than', not 'less than or equal to' for running a loop once for each index in a zero-indexed array.